How to move desktop icons grid from top 150 pixel below
Is there any WinAPI method to move desktop icons grid from top of the screen for example 150 pixel below?
I am using this Github code to move icons below from top of the screen but its not working icons again reset to their default positions:
internal class Desktop
{
    private readonly IntPtr _desktopHandle;
    private readonly List<string> _currentIconsOrder;

    public Desktop()
    {
        _desktopHandle = Win32.GetDesktopWindow(Win32.DesktopWindow.SysListView32);

        AutomationElement el = AutomationElement.FromHandle(_desktopHandle);

        TreeWalker walker = TreeWalker.ContentViewWalker;
        _currentIconsOrder = new List<string>();
        for (AutomationElement child = walker.GetFirstChild(el);
            child != null;
            child = walker.GetNextSibling(child))
        {
            _currentIconsOrder.Add(child.Current.Name);
        }
    }

    private int GetIconsNumber()
    {
        return (int)Win32.SendMessage(_desktopHandle, Win32.LVM_GETITEMCOUNT, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
    }

    public NamedDesktopPoint[] GetIconsPositions()
    {
        uint desktopProcessId;
        Win32.GetWindowThreadProcessId(_desktopHandle, out desktopProcessId);

        IntPtr desktopProcessHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
        try
        {
            desktopProcessHandle = Win32.OpenProcess(Win32.ProcessAccess.VmOperation | Win32.ProcessAccess.VmRead |
                Win32.ProcessAccess.VmWrite, false, desktopProcessId);

            return GetIconsPositions(desktopProcessHandle);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (desktopProcessHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
            { Win32.CloseHandle(desktopProcessHandle); }
        }
    }

    private NamedDesktopPoint[] GetIconsPositions(IntPtr desktopProcessHandle)
    {
        IntPtr sharedMemoryPointer = IntPtr.Zero;

        try
        {
            sharedMemoryPointer = Win32.VirtualAllocEx(desktopProcessHandle, IntPtr.Zero, 4096, Win32.AllocationType.Reserve | Win32.AllocationType.Commit, Win32.MemoryProtection.ReadWrite);

            return GetIconsPositions(desktopProcessHandle, sharedMemoryPointer);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (sharedMemoryPointer != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                Win32.VirtualFreeEx(desktopProcessHandle, sharedMemoryPointer, 0, Win32.FreeType.Release);
            }
        }

    }

    private NamedDesktopPoint[] GetIconsPositions(IntPtr desktopProcessHandle, IntPtr sharedMemoryPointer)
    {
        var listOfPoints = new LinkedList<NamedDesktopPoint>();

        var numberOfIcons = GetIconsNumber();

        for (int itemIndex = 0; itemIndex < numberOfIcons; itemIndex++)
        {
            uint numberOfBytes = 0;
            DesktopPoint[] points = new DesktopPoint[1];

            Win32.WriteProcessMemory(desktopProcessHandle, sharedMemoryPointer,
                Marshal.UnsafeAddrOfPinnedArrayElement(points, 0),
                Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(DesktopPoint)),
                ref numberOfBytes);

            Win32.SendMessage(_desktopHandle, Win32.LVM_GETITEMPOSITION, itemIndex, sharedMemoryPointer);

            Win32.ReadProcessMemory(desktopProcessHandle, sharedMemoryPointer,
                Marshal.UnsafeAddrOfPinnedArrayElement(points, 0),
                Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(DesktopPoint)),
                ref numberOfBytes);

            var point = points[0];
            listOfPoints.AddLast(new NamedDesktopPoint(_currentIconsOrder[itemIndex], point.X, point.Y));
        }

        return listOfPoints.ToArray();
    }

    public void SetIconPositions(IEnumerable<NamedDesktopPoint> iconPositions)
    {
        foreach (var position in iconPositions)
        {
            var iconIndex = _currentIconsOrder.IndexOf(position.Name);
            if (iconIndex == -1)
            { continue; }

            Win32.SendMessage(_desktopHandle, Win32.LVM_SETITEMPOSITION, iconIndex, Win32.MakeLParam(position.X, position.Y));
        }
    }

    public void SetDefaultIconPositions(IEnumerable<NamedDesktopPoint> iconPositions)
    {
        foreach (var position in iconPositions)
        {
            var iconIndex = _currentIconsOrder.IndexOf(position.Name);
            if (iconIndex == -1)
            { continue; }

            Win32.SendMessage(_desktopHandle, Win32.LVM_SETITEMPOSITION, iconIndex, Win32.MakeLParam(position.X, position.Y));
        }
    }

    public void Refresh()
    {
        Win32.PostMessage(_desktopHandle, Win32.WM_KEYDOWN, Win32.VK_F5, 0);

        Win32.SHChangeNotify(0x8000000, 0x1000, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
    }
}

I would like to achieve this GUI:

Image details: Application height is 150 pixel and I am try to move icons below that application.
Is this possible to achieve this?

Question Edited:
I don't know why it's not clear! While its clearly stated in question that I am trying to move desktop icons grid (not desktop icons).
As, we all know windows desktop have a ListView (SysListView32) to store its icons on desktop, and I'm trying to move this ListView (or desktop grid) from top of the screen below 150 pixel. And, my application (which height is 150 pixel) is placed at top of the screen (see in above image).
And I'm able to get desktop ListView (SysListView32) using this code:
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr GetShellWindow();

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc lpEnumFunc, IntPtr lParam);

public delegate bool EnumWindowsProc(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr lParam);

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern int GetClassName(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder lpClassName, int nMaxCount);        

public static IntPtr GetDesktopWindow(DesktopWindow desktopWindow)
{
    IntPtr _ProgMan = GetShellWindow();
    IntPtr _SHELLDLL_DefViewParent = _ProgMan;
    IntPtr _SHELLDLL_DefView = FindWindowEx(_ProgMan, IntPtr.Zero, "SHELLDLL_DefView", null);
    IntPtr _SysListView32 = FindWindowEx(_SHELLDLL_DefView, IntPtr.Zero, "SysListView32", "FolderView");

    if (_SHELLDLL_DefView == IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        EnumWindows((hwnd, lParam) =>
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder(256);
            GetClassName(hwnd, sb, sb.Capacity);

            if (sb.ToString() == "WorkerW")
            {
                IntPtr child = FindWindowEx(hwnd, IntPtr.Zero, "SHELLDLL_DefView", null);
                if (child != IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    _SHELLDLL_DefViewParent = hwnd;
                    _SHELLDLL_DefView = child;
                    _SysListView32 = FindWindowEx(child, IntPtr.Zero, "SysListView32", "FolderView"); ;
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }, IntPtr.Zero);
    }

    switch (desktopWindow)
    {
        case DesktopWindow.ProgMan:
            return _ProgMan;
        case DesktopWindow.SHELLDLL_DefViewParent:
            return _SHELLDLL_DefViewParent;
        case DesktopWindow.SHELLDLL_DefView:
            return _SHELLDLL_DefView;
        case DesktopWindow.SysListView32:
            return _SysListView32;
        default:
            return IntPtr.Zero;
    }
}


Probably not only an unclear question, but also a duplicate of: How can I programmatically manipulate Windows desktop icon locations?

please wait I am editing my question

Please check my edited question

From the answer I linked above: "If I'm not mistaken the desktop is just a ListView, and you'll have to send the LVM_SETITEMPOSITION message to the handle of the desktop.". The link to Microsoft says: "Returns TRUE if successful, or FALSE otherwise.", and you do NOT seem to check that return value. The question might not be a duplicate, but it needs "debugging details" ....

But LVM_SETITEMPOSITION is a message  which does not returns anything. Otherwise ListView_SetItemPosition macro will return, but i am not using this macro method.

The LVM_SETITEMPOSITION message does return a value. The same as the macro (which is the same thing)

how to use it ?

Use SelectAndPositionItems, which is the documented and supported API for manipulating desktop icons.

Voting to reopen, the question is clear enough, there's currently no C# answer to this and I have one

It's not manipulating desktop icons, instead needs to move or manipulate desktop icons grid (which class name is SysListView32 may be).

"Voting to reopen, the question is clear enough, there's currently no C# answer to this ..." -> also voted to re-open. My reason to close was the, initially, missing info which is solved now too.

I check the code from the Github link you referred to in the question. And that code does work OK (after modifying the save XML, and loading it, an icon is moving). My conclusion is you need to do some debugging. Or you need to share more info on "but its not working icons again reset to their default positions" When is this reset happening? When I run IconsSaveRestore.exe load .... I only see the icon for which the location changed moving, but not resetting.

When I use this code to move icons positions some pixels below they doesn't persists their positions and icons reset to default positions. Now its solved by using @SimonMourier answer.

"Is this possible to achieve this?" - No. The listview control doesn't support modifying the grid origin. You can toggle the snap-to-grid functionality only.

any other workaround?

There is no public interface to customize the Shell. If that is what you're after, you'll have to write a full Shell replacement.

Here's a sample C# Console Application using the official API IFolderView::SelectAndPositionItems method that can be used for that:
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace MyConsoleApp;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // we basically follow https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130318-00/?p=4933
        dynamic app = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Shell.Application"));
        var windows = app.Windows;

        const int SWC_DESKTOP = 8;
        const int SWFO_NEEDDISPATCH = 1;
        var hwnd = 0;
        var disp = windows.FindWindowSW(Type.Missing, Type.Missing, SWC_DESKTOP, ref hwnd, SWFO_NEEDDISPATCH);

        var sp = (IServiceProvider)disp;
        var SID_STopLevelBrowser = new Guid("4c96be40-915c-11cf-99d3-00aa004ae837");

        var browser = (IShellBrowser)sp.QueryService(SID_STopLevelBrowser, typeof(IShellBrowser).GUID);
        var view = (IFolderView)browser.QueryActiveShellView();
        var view2 = (IFolderView2)view;

        // get all items, dump & sets their position (here y+= 150)
        for (var i = 0; i < view.ItemCount(); i++)
        {
            // get some item's info to be able to determine if we want to move it or not
            var item = view2.GetItem(i, typeof(IShellItem).GUID);
            Console.WriteLine(item.GetDisplayName(SIGDN.SIGDN_DESKTOPABSOLUTEPARSING));

            var pidl = view.Item(i);
            view.GetItemPosition(pidl, out var pt);
            Console.WriteLine("Current position: " + pt.x + ", " + pt.y);

            pt.y += 150;
            view.SelectAndPositionItems(1, new IntPtr[] { pidl }, new POINT[] { pt }, SVSIF.SVSI_POSITIONITEM);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }

    [ComImport, Guid("6D5140C1-7436-11CE-8034-00AA006009FA"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    public interface IServiceProvider
    {
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)]
        object QueryService([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] Guid service, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] Guid riid);
    }

    // note: for the following interfaces, not all methods are defined as we don't use them here
    [ComImport, Guid("000214E2-0000-0000-C000-000000000046"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    public interface IShellBrowser
    {
        void _VtblGap1_12(); // skip 12 methods https://stackoverflow.com/a/47567206/403671

        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)]
        object QueryActiveShellView();
    }

    [ComImport, Guid("cde725b0-ccc9-4519-917e-325d72fab4ce"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    public interface IFolderView
    {
        void _VtblGap1_3(); // skip 3 methods

        IntPtr Item(int iItemIndex);
        int ItemCount(uint uFlags = 0);

        void _VtblGap2_3(); // skip 2 methods

        void GetItemPosition(IntPtr pidl, out POINT ppt);

        void _VtblGap1_4(); // skip 4 methods

        void SelectAndPositionItems(int cidl, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 0)] IntPtr[] apidl, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 0)] POINT[] apt, SVSIF dwFlags);

        // more undefined methods
    }

    [ComImport, Guid("1af3a467-214f-4298-908e-06b03e0b39f9"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    public interface IFolderView2
    {
        void _VtblGap1_26(); // skip 14 (IFolderView) + 12 methods

        IShellItem GetItem(int iItemIndex, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] Guid riid);

        // more undefined methods
    }

    [ComImport, Guid("43826d1e-e718-42ee-bc55-a1e261c37bfe"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    public interface IShellItem
    {
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)]
        object BindToHandler(System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IBindCtx pbc, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] Guid bhid, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] Guid riid);

        IShellItem GetParent();

        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
        string GetDisplayName(SIGDN sigdnName);

        // more undefined methods
    }

    public struct POINT
    {
        public int x;
        public int y;
    }

    public enum SIGDN
    {
        SIGDN_NORMALDISPLAY,
        SIGDN_PARENTRELATIVEPARSING,
        SIGDN_DESKTOPABSOLUTEPARSING,
        SIGDN_PARENTRELATIVEEDITING,
        SIGDN_DESKTOPABSOLUTEEDITING,
        SIGDN_FILESYSPATH,
        SIGDN_URL,
        SIGDN_PARENTRELATIVEFORADDRESSBAR,
        SIGDN_PARENTRELATIVE,
        SIGDN_PARENTRELATIVEFORUI
    }

    [Flags]
    public enum SVSIF
    {
        SVSI_DESELECT = 0,
        SVSI_SELECT = 0x1,
        SVSI_EDIT = 0x3,
        SVSI_DESELECTOTHERS = 0x4,
        SVSI_ENSUREVISIBLE = 0x8,
        SVSI_FOCUSED = 0x10,
        SVSI_TRANSLATEPT = 0x20,
        SVSI_SELECTIONMARK = 0x40,
        SVSI_POSITIONITEM = 0x80,
        SVSI_CHECK = 0x100,
        SVSI_CHECK2 = 0x200,
        SVSI_KEYBOARDSELECT = 0x401,
        SVSI_NOTAKEFOCUS = 0x40000000
    }
}

PS: this code presumes the icon are not automatically arranged by the the shell configuration, otherwise it will have not effect.

Thanks for your answer! It works but there are some other issues arises after running your code. First Issue: Its moving the icons in groups, it moves 6 icons group from top 300px below and another group having 300px gap between first group and so on... Second Issue: If we create new icon its again placed at top left corner of the desktop screen.

The code is not moving the icon in groups, it's moving icon 1 by 1 by changing its pixel position, that's it. It's up to you to decide where each icon should go.
